# Group by month and date in mongodb and display the list

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

My DB products schema structure

```
{ "_id" :  "507d95d5719dbef170f15bf9" , "name" : "AC3 Series Charger", "type" : "accessory", "price" : 19,"created":"1626083461034"}
{ "_id" :  "507d95d5719dbef170f15bfa" , "name" : "AC3 Case Green", "type" : "case" ,  "price" : 12, "created":"1625805979235"}
{ "_id" :  "507d95d5719dbef170f15bfb" , "name" : "Phone Extended Warranty", "type" : "warranty", "price" : 38,"created":"1624374320653" }
{ "_id" :  "507d95d5719dbef170f15bfc" , "name" : "AC3 Case Black", "type" :  "case" , "price" : 12.5,"created":"1624606153646" }
{ "_id" :  "507d95d5719dbef170f15bfd" , "name" : "AC3 Case Red", "type" : "case" , "price" : 12, "created":"1624362066717"}
{ "_id" :  "507d95d5719dbef170f15bfe" , "name" : "Phone Service Basic Plan", "type" : "service", "price":9.5,"created":"1624446320186"}
{ "_id" :  "507d95d5719dbef170f15bff" , "name" : "Phone Service Core Plan", "type" : "service", "price" :3.5,"created":"1624605403064"}
{ "_id" :  "507d95d5719dbef170f15c00" , "name" : "Phone Service Family Plan", "type" : "service", "price":10.4,"created":"1624446320173"}
```

I want to get the records based **`month and day`** and for that, I've written a query like below

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
            _id: { month:{ "$month": { "$toDate": "$created" }, day: "$day"  } },
            product: { "$push": "$name" }
    }}
  ])
```

but it is giving the error

```
An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $month: { $toDate: \"$created\" }, day: \"$day\" }
```

Expected output

```
 {
      month:5
      day:12
      products:[
          {
            "name" : "Phone Service Family Plan"
          },
          {"name" : "Phone Service Core Plan"}
      ]
  }
```

Comment: `"$day"` - you don't have that field in the sample documents. I think you can also convert the `created` field to `day` using the appropriate aggregate operator (I think there is a `$day` aggregate operator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your string to long first by using [$toLong](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/) and also use [$dayOfMonth](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/) operator since there's no `$day` in MongoDB:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            _id: {
                month: { "$month": { "$toDate": { $toLong: "$created" } } },
                day: { "$dayOfMonth": { "$toDate": { $toLong: "$created" } } }
                
            },
            product: {
                "$push": "$name"
                }
            }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.month",
            monthDays: {
                $push: {
                    day: "$_id.day",
                    product: "$product"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            month: "$_id",
            monthDays: 1
        }
    },
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FPhASZBpyA-)

Comment: month data is grouping. check the 7th month results

Comment: @ram12393 I don't fully understand what's wrong, could you paste expected result for given data?

Comment: This solution groups by pair of (month and day) which is (I believe) what you were expecting

Comment: If you check your query results , there is 7 months records are multiples with different date. My question is how we can do same month records under single array with respect to day rather than multiples.

Comment: did you get my question ??

Comment: @ram12393 I need you to show me your expected output format :)

Comment: here you go expected =>https://pasteboard.co/KaPtx1f.png

Comment: @ram12393 that helps, modified my answer